# How we can use bottomSheet in fragment for RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a simple project, and I want to use bottom sheet for list items in fragment, every things looks good, but after build the project, app crash like that,

> a null object reference for row_list.setOnLongClickListener

I do not know where is the problem and how I will fix this problem, maybe my approach is not correct, any idea will be appreciated.

**fragment_list:**

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".view.ListFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/row_list"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="60dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

   </FrameLayout>
```

**ListFragment:**

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        row_list.setOnLongClickListener {

            val bottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment = RowItemMenuFragment()
            bottomSheetFragment.show(requireFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.tag)

            true
        }}
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        return view

    }}}
```

**RowItemMenuFragment:**

```
class RowItemMenuFragment() : BottomSheetDialogFragment()  {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_row_item_menu, container, false)

    }

    override fun onCreate(@Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme)

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During `onCreate()` views are not initialized completely or are in ambiguous state.

Simple answer is to move the view logic to `onViewCreated()`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        row_list.setOnLongClickListener {

            val bottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment = RowItemMenuFragment()
            bottomSheetFragment.show(requireFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.tag)

            true
        }
}
```

Comment: tnx so much it work, but when I long click the list items, bottom sheet not work, any idea?

Comment: Try using `supportFragmentManager`

Comment: I use it it is work, but the same problem, row_list is id for recycler view, I am not sure which id I need, is it possbile to use row item  id?

Comment: add a `onClickListner` on `recyclerView` , see [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Naruto/blob/c4a3f5ae6cb75c64c12311b5d098a19ebc855cf7/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/naruto/ui/main/character/list/CharacterListAdapter.kt#L19) and impl [here](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Naruto/blob/c4a3f5ae6cb75c64c12311b5d098a19ebc855cf7/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/naruto/ui/main/character/list/CharacterListFragment.kt#L51)

Comment: tnx so much but I didnt get it how implemet adapter in fragment

Comment: just add onClickListner as lambda

Comment: is it possible u update ur answer for item row id with example adapter?